# would minimongo cache across subscriptions?

Tags: javascript, meteor

If I have a subscription inside an `Tracker.autorun()`, the publish takes a variable selector, means that every time, the return may vary, would minimongo cache all the docs returned from all the publications? or each time, it clears all its documents and only preserve the returned docs from previous publication?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is clever enough to keep track of the current document set that each client has for each publisher. When the publisher reruns, it knows to only send the **difference** between the sets. Let's use the following sequence as an example:

1. subscribe for posts: `a,b,c`
2. rerun the subscription for posts `b,c,d`
3. server sends a `removed` message for `a` and an `added` message for `d`.

Note this will not happen if you stopped the subscription prior to rerunning it.

Comment: so you mean, minimongo keeps in sync with the results from last publication? if my last publication returned 0 doc, does that mean minimongo would also return 0 doc using collection.find().count()?

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) Yes, assuming you only had one subscription for posts (if you had multiple subscriptions they could overlap).